# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY while Inserting Null timestamp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data, jpql

I have an insert query where along with other fields , I am inserting Timestamp. Now whenever, value of Timestamp is null, I am getting the error -

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY
```

I am using oracle 11g.

Query is :

```
@Modifying
@Query(value ="INSERT INTO mams_asset a ( a.mams_asset_id, a.mams_folder_id, a.asset_name, a.gist, a.last_modified_date, a.last_exported_date, a.created_date ) VALUES (hextoraw(?1), hextoraw(?2), ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6 , ?7)" , nativeQuery = true)
int insertIntoMamsAsset(String mamsAssetId, String mamsFolderId, String assetName, String gist, Timestamp lastModifiedDate, Timestamp lastExportedDate, Timestamp createdDate);
```

This is though spring data JPA one. I tried using this approach too but same error:

```
public int insertIntoMamsAsset(String mamsAssetId, String mamsFolderId, String assetName, String gist, Timestamp lastModifiedDate, Timestamp lastExportedDate, Timestamp createdDate){

        final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO mams_asset a ( a.mams_asset_id, a.mams_folder_id, a.asset_name, a.gist, a.last_modified_date, a.last_exported_date, a.created_date ) VALUES (hextoraw(?), hextoraw(?), ?, ?, ?, ? , ?)")
                .setParameter(1, mamsAssetId)
                .setParameter(2,mamsFolderId)
                .setParameter(3,assetName)
                .setParameter(4,gist)
                .setParameter(5,lastModifiedDate)
                .setParameter(6,lastExportedDate)
                .setParameter(7,createdDate);

        return query.executeUpdate();


    }
```

Though the query seems long but you can focus only on Timestamp field that's what is generating error.

What is the work around for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
 final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO mams_asset a ( a.mams_asset_id, a.mams_folder_id, a.asset_name, a.gist, a.last_modified_date, " +
                "a.last_exported_date, a.created_date ) VALUES (hextoraw(?), hextoraw(?), ?, ?, ?, ? , ?)")
                .setParameter(1, mamsAssetId)
                .setParameter(2, mamsFolderId)
                .setParameter(3, assetName)
                .setParameter(4, gist)
                .setParameter(5, lastModifiedDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                .setParameter(6, lastExportedDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
                .setParameter(7, createdDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

I added `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` in setParameter.

Answer (score 0):

It happens cause your table dont admit null value for last_modified_date.

Try to check if the input value lastModifiedDate is null or no before launche the query like this

```
if(lastModifiedDate = null){
Timestamp myModifiedDate = new Timestamp(0001-01-01 00:00:00);
}
```

Or simply change the database like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN date TIMESTAMP NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This oracle message is happens when you try to insert a value to a column from different types for more detail :

http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00932_inconsistent_datatypes_expected_string_got_string.htm

now to insert a date value better to use Calendar class or Date class.